# Can't revert to using Virtual Box after using Docker on Windows after latest update

Tags: windows, docker, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have been running Ubuntu in a VirtualBox machine. I could always switch between using Docker and using VirtualBox by turning off Hyper-V windows feature in Control Panel.
However, after Windows 1903 update I tried switching back to VirtualBox, same as before, but I got ERROR_SUCCESS (Last=0xc000000d/87 (VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED). This error is the same everyone gets when they haven't turned off Hyper-V in Control Panel.

Has anyone else encountered this problem and does anyone know a simpler solution to switching between VirtualBox and Docker that would not be affected by future OS updates ?

Comment: So close hyperv not help?

Comment: @atline No. I mentioned I uninstalled the Hyper-V windows feature in Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

RUN > CMD(as Administrator) > bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
Then reboot host machine

Comment: Can you provide more context? Why would this solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The following 3 steps worked for me:

1. Run CMD (as Administrator) to open a terminal
2. In the terminal, type `bcdedit /copy {current} /d "No Hyper-V"`

You should get a message of the form: `The entry was successfully copied to {ff-23-113-824e-5c5144ea}.`. Of course, `ff-23-113-824e-5c5144ea` is an example of identifier in this example. You'll get another one.

Finally, use this identifier to run the following command:

3. `bcdedit /set {ff-23-113-824e-5c5144ea} hypervisorlaunchtype off`

You should get a message of the form `The operation completed successfully.`

I got this from [SwitchEasilyBetweenVirtualBoxAndHyperV](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchEasilyBetweenVirtualBoxAndHyperVWithABCDEditBootEntryInWindows81.aspx).